# Is there a paired t-test for a multiple-to-one correspondence between data sets?

Tags: distributions, t-test

Imagine we want to see of the distributions of a statistic are different between samples A and B and that there is a several-to-one correspondence between the two.

For example members of A may be sentences from English and for each element a of A we have 10 sentences in B each consisting of random shuffles of the words in A.
The statistic can be the number of consecutive letters in the sentence that are consecutive in the alphabet too.

Is there a paired t-test for such a situation? If so how can it be done in R? (I've read a paper mentioning doing such a test without giving enough detail about how it was done.)

Comment: When there are multiple related/associated things the word "paired" won't work -- and nor would t-test in general.You should describe what variable you're looking at in these sentences and what you're interested in finding out about it (you mention no variables of interest, nor any hypotheses at all). The situation sounds broadly like a treatment vs several controls sort of situation, but it sounds like we might potentially be dealing with count variables with potentially small counts (so something related to a t-test may not be suitable). Please give details about what you're trying to do

Comment: I added a bit more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use one line in your data-set per shuffled element in B. In the multiple A column cells corresponding to a B element, you would always put the same value. You can then make a paired test on this data-set in the usual way.

Of course the test would not recognise possibly differing multiplicities of the B elements and give each row of the set the same weight

edit: On second thoughts I'm quite sure there are problems with sample independence making this a pseudoreplication if we count every line separately as I suggested.

Comment: As I understand, you mean repeating each element of A 10 times so that it becomes even with B?

Comment: Yes. If you always have 10 B for an A.